# angularjs nested directives using ng-repeat and primitive data types

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to generate multiple nested views based on object data with AngularJS.  It's also a requirement to use an array of strings (being able to add and remove them). I know most suggest to use [{value:""},{value:""}] instead of an array of strings.  However, I need to return the result (to the controller) as an array of strings.

The difficulty is that I can only have 2 objects.  One that supplies the data and another that holds all models that need to be looped through and rendered/compiled.

Is there a way I can loop through an array of strings and return the selected ones into a model specified by a key. i.e {key:"one", list:["one","two","three"]}

Here is a plunker I started (not currently working): http://plnkr.co/edit/iXel2FJtJtdRoET3xQn4?p=info

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to go for, but I was able to edit your plunk and get it working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1PoE3ayr0inKoWilm05b?p=preview

You used data/model interchangeably in a few places and that was causing one of the issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  The problem I was having was actually to do with object references.  In the end I had to use angular.copy to create a deep copy.  Fixed my issue!